# Convert form data to object (DTO)

Tags: java, dto

I have this route in controller which accepts - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/browser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/xml"}, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> processServerCallback(@RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String> formVars) {
    System.out.println(formVars);
    return null;
}
```

Now I need to convert `formVars` to my DTO object. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show the DTO? and maybe an example of the formVars map?

Comment: what framework are you using? what is your DTO?

Comment: I am using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Say, formVars looks like this:

```
public class FormVars{
private String name;
private int age;
//constructors and getters and setters
}`
```

Then in your controller method, you need to replace `@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String>` with `@RequestBody FormVars formVars`